# Exact ODE $\bigg(3x^2\tan{y}-\frac{2y^3}{x^3}\bigg)dx+ \bigg(x^3 \sec^2{y}+4y^3+\frac{3y^2}{x^2}\bigg)dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following exact ODE:

$$\bigg(3x^2\tan{y}-\frac{2y^3}{x^3}\bigg)dx+ \bigg(x^3 \sec^2{y}+4y^3+\frac{3y^2}{x^2}\bigg)dx=0$$

My instructor gave us the following formula:

$$\int_{x_0}^xM(x,y_0)dx+\int_{y_0}^y N(x,y)dy=C$$
and after doing these integrals, we're supposed to take $x_0 = 0$ and $y_0=0$. But I get to this expression:

$$\tan{y}(x^3-x_0^3)+y^3\bigg( \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2_0} \bigg) + x^3 (\tan{y}- \tan{y_0}) + (y^4-y_0^4) + \frac{1}{x^2} (y^3-y_0^3)=C$$

As it seems, the term $\bigg( \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2_0} \bigg)$ can't be evaluated with $x_0 = 0$. Does this formula works for finding general integrals of ODE's or is it better for particular integrals?

For context, I used this same formula but for: $$(3x^2+6xy^2)dx + (6x^2y+4y^3)dy =0 $$

and it worked, resulting in: $$x^3+3x^2y^2+y^4=C$$ which is indeed the general integral of the ODE.

Thanks.

Comment: You can write your ODE as $$\bigg(3x^2\tan{y}-\frac{2y^3}{x^3}\bigg)dx+ \bigg(x^3 \sec^2{y}+4y^3+\frac{3y^2}{x^2}\bigg)dy=d\Bigg(x^3\tan(y)+y^4+\frac{y^3}{x^2}\Bigg)=0$$ This implies $x^2\tan(y)+y^4+\frac{y^3}{x^2}\equiv C$. In other words, solving an exact ODE requires that you calculate the potential function for the conservative vector field $$F(x,y)=\bigg<3x^2\tan{y}-\frac{2y^3}{x^3},x^3 \sec^2{y}+4y^3+\frac{3y^2}{x^2}\bigg>$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that:
$$\partial_x F(x,y)=M(x,y)$$
$$ F(x,y)=\int M(x,y)dx=\int\bigg(3x^2\tan{y}-\frac{2y^3}{x^3}\bigg)dx$$
$$F(x,y)=x^3\tan y+\frac{y^3}{x^2}+g(y)$$
Wa also have that :
$$\partial_y F(x,y)=N(x,y)$$
$$\partial_y F(x,y)=x^3\sec^2 y+3\frac{y^2}{x^2}+g'(y)$$
$$\bigg(x^3 \sec^2{y}+4y^3+\frac{3y^2}{x^2}\bigg)=x^3\sec^2 y+3\frac{y^2}{x^2}+g'(y)$$
$$4y^3=g'(y)$$
$$\implies g(y)=y^4+C$$
So that:
$$F(x,y)=x^3\tan y+\frac{y^3}{x^2}+y^4+c$$
And the solution is :
$$F(x,y)=K$$
$$\implies x^3\tan y+\frac{y^3}{x^2}+y^4=C$$